# jQuery Mobile footer navbar stays on page after a $('#page').trigger('create')

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-mobile

In my webapp i dynamicaly load data via ajax. After loading i trigger a "create" on the page i have changed. But after the create, the navbar on bottom (fixed) stays on bottom, even when i switch to another page without any navbar.

Problem is, that inside the dynamic content are some jQuery Mobile elements which have to be redrawed (buttons)

Page looks like this:

```html
 <div data-role="page" id="fax" data-title="Fax" data-theme="b">
        <div data-role="header" data-theme="b">
            <a href="#faxe" data-direction="reverse" data-icon="arrow-l">back</a>
            <h1>Fax</h1>
        </div>
        <div data-role="ui-content" role="main">
            <div id="myAjaxContent"></div>
        </div>
        <div data-id="fax" data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" data-theme="b">    
            <div data-role="navbar" data-iconpos="top">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#fax" data-icon="star" class="ui-state-persist ui-btn-active">Fax</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#map" data-icon="home">Map</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

My Ajax:

```
$.post('ajax.php',{ action: 'fax', ID: faxID, lat: lat, lon: lon },function(data){
        $('#fax').find('div[data-role="ui-content"]').find('#myAjaxContent').html(data.fax);
        $('#fax').trigger("create");
        $( ":mobile-pagecontainer" ).pagecontainer( "change", "#fax" );                
    },'json');
```

Comment: `$('#fax').find('div[data-role="ui-content"]').find('#myAjaxContent').html(data.fax).enhanceWithin()`. trigger create is deprecated and will be removed.

Comment: Thanks Omar, this works for me!